# Evaluation of probabilistic predictions

Tags: machine-learning, probability, scoring-rules

In the [2010 KDD cup](http://pslcdatashop.web.cmu.edu/KDDCup/), participants were tasked with estimating the probability that a student would solve a particular exam question. The competition winner was whoever produced the lowest root square mean error (RMSE). Is there some theorem that guarantees that guessing the true probabilities provides the lowest value?

Also, it's hard to interpret the results because, the RMSE will be non-zero even if we were perfectly able to guess the true probabilities of a user getting a question right. It would seem that there should be a method of seeing that, say 71% of the questions we marked as the student of having 70% probability of solving were done correctly (and so on for our other predictions), so the algorithm should produce a near zero value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guessing the true probabilities provides the lowest RMSE in expectation. First, note that minimizing the RMSE is the same as minimizing the MSE.

Let $Z_i$ be the binary random variable representing whether the student gets question $i$ right; let $θ_i=P[Z_i=1]$ be the probability of that event, and let $p_i$ be your guess of that probability. Then the MSE is $∑_i (Z_i-p_i)^2$, and

$E[MSE]=∑_i θ_i(1-p_i)^2+(1-θ_i)p_i^2$

You can differentiate wrt $p_i$ to see that the minimum is attained when $p_i=θ_i$.

What you propose in the second paragraph would not be optimal. Suppose that out of 100 questions, the student gets the first 71 correct, and the last 29 wrong. By your measure, someone who guessed 70% for all questions should get an excellent score. But I think you'll agree that someone who guessed 100% for the first 71 questions, and 0% for the last 29, actually did a much better prediction job.

Comment: That's a neat proof. I don't suppose that theorem has a name by any chance?